# Backporting: Does anyone have a function to mimic bash 4 associative array?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to make changes in my script that uses associative array, so that the script may be used in older versions (before v4.0) of bash which did not support associative array. Can someone suggest how this may be implemented using a function (without external commands)?

The functions has to support following:

```
mimic_associative_array --set __MY_VAR_NAME "my_key01" "my_val01"
mimic_associative_array --get __MY_VAR_NAME "my_key01"
```

(The variable name regexp. [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* and for keys and values regex. [[:print:]]*)

Preferably, the function/script should not use any temporary file(s) for intermediate processing.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 but I need to backport my script to be able to use MacOS actually, without having to upgrade my bash there.

Comment: For MacOS >= Catalina it might be simpler to convert the script to zsh?

Comment: @steeldriver, For my bash script uses many indexed arrays too, and manipulation of indices, it seems it will take more effort than backporting to v3.2. For, now, backporting to v3.2 is done, working on translation to zsh, which seems to require much more effort.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following and it works to simplest of my needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a __MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARNAME=()
declare -a __MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARKEY=()
declare -a __MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARVALUE=()
declare -i __MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__INDEX=0

function mimic_associative_array() {

    declare func_arg=""
    declare assoc_array_name=""
    declare assoc_key_name=""
    declare assoc_value=""


    while [[ ${#} -gt 0 ]] ; do
        func_arg="${1}"
        case ${func_arg} in
            -s|--set)
                shift
                assoc_array_name="${1}"
                ## Support only the following regex. type variable names:
                if [[ ! "${assoc_array_name}" =~ ^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$ ]] ; then
                    echo "[${FUNCNAME[0]}()] Error. Unsupported variable name." >&2
                    return 1
                else
                    __MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARNAME[${__MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__INDEX}]="${assoc_array_name}"
                fi
                shift
                assoc_key_name="${1}"
                if [[ ! "${assoc_key_name}" =~ ^[[:print:]]*$ ]] ; then
                    echo "[${FUNCNAME[0]}()] Error. Unsupported key name." >&2
                    return 1
                else
                    __MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARKEY[${__MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__INDEX}]="${assoc_key_name}"
                fi
                shift
                assoc_value="${1}"
                if [[ ! "${assoc_value}" =~ ^[[:print:]]*$ ]] ; then
                    echo "[${FUNCNAME[0]}()] Error. Unsupported value." >&2
                    return 1
                else
                    __MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARVALUE[${__MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__INDEX}]="${assoc_value}"
                fi
                shift
                let __MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__INDEX++
                return 0
            ;;
            -g|--get)
                shift
                assoc_array_name="${1}"
                shift
                assoc_key_name="${1}"
                declare -i int_counter=0
                while : ; do
                    if [[ "${__MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARNAME[${int_counter}]}" == "${assoc_array_name}" && "${__MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARKEY[${int_counter}]}" == "${assoc_key_name}" ]] ; then
                        printf "${__MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARVALUE[${int_counter}]}"
                        return 0
                    fi
                    let int_counter++
                    if [[ ${int_counter} -gt ${#__MIMIC_ASSOC_ARRAY__VARNAME[@]} ]] ; then
                        break
                    fi
                done
                return 2
            ;;
        esac
    done
}

mimic_associative_array --set __MY_ASSOC03 "key01" "a03:val01"
mimic_associative_array --get __MY_ASSOC03 "key01"
```

Comment: This is really a strong indication that you should be using an actual programming/scripting language and not the shell. I mean, kudos for this, it's a neat approach, but if you just used perl or python or anything designed to write programs in (i.e. not a shell) it would make your life much easier and you would have no portability issues.